# Setting a path in my azure pipeline for specific project folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[how my 2 files look in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzhq8.png)

As shown in the image, I have two csproj files and I do not want to include the backup file in my pipeline deployment but Im not sure how to set the path for it. Can someone look at my pipeline and see how I can just go about inluding just the Nftexport....csproj in the run but not the backup one as shown in the image. I keep getting failures as it doesnt have the support dependencies needed and I dont want it included in the run anyways. As shown in my code for pipeline setup how it currently looks. I need to set up the right path but Im quite unsure

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - dev
 paths:
   include:
     - NftImportExportScanner/*

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Set .NET Core to 6.x
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '39b14414-e819-472c-a8c9-e1b150e85a52/1e69f816-5f54-4793-9746-2a8eed83160b'
    projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/*.csproj'
    includeNuGetOrg: true


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/*.csproj'     
    zipAfterPublish: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output publish_output --no-restore'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/NftImportExportScanner'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/NftImportExportScanner/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildNumber).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Export Artifacts
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop_$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

Comment: You could update the projects: lines in each task to point to the exact project file you want to use or maybe rename the backup project to remove or change the csproj extension so it's not included by this syntax: projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/*.csproj'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current YAML definition, the path: `**/NftImportExportScanner/*.csproj` will loop all csproj files under the folder NftImportExportScanner.

> Can someone look at my pipeline and see how I can just go about inluding just the Nftexport....csproj in the run but not the backup one as shown in the image.

To meet your requirement, you can specify a specific csproj file in the Projects field in the DotNetCoreCLI task.

For example: `projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/NftImportExportScanner.csproj'`

When you use the dotnet Publish task, you need to set the `publishWebProjects: false`. Then you can select the project.

For example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/NftImportExportScanner.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output publish_output --no-restore'
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

Full YAML sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - dev
 paths:
   include:
     - NftImportExportScanner/*

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Set .NET Core to 6.x
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '39b14414-e819-472c-a8c9-e1b150e85a52/1e69f816-5f54-4793-9746-2a8eed83160b'
    projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/NftImportExportScanner.csproj'
    includeNuGetOrg: true


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/NftImportExportScanner.csproj'     
    zipAfterPublish: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/NftImportExportScanner/NftImportExportScanner.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.sourcesdirectory)/NftImportExportScanner/publish_output --no-restore'
    zipAfterPublish: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/NftImportExportScanner/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildNumber).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Export Artifacts
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop_$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

Comment: Its failing at the archive stage by no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/NftImportExportScanner/publish_output'

Comment: @DarraghMartin you can set the output path: --output $(build.sourcesdirectory)/NftImportExportScanner/publish_output in dotnet publish

Comment: You can refer to my update in the answer

Comment: Thanks for all that Kevin. Greatly appreciated. As it turns out, there is a lot of old dependencies in the files which isnt allow this to build as not supported. I will need to look into it further. Thanks